# ASP.NET Core - How to restart session timeout programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm migrating a .NET 4 Framework ASP.NET MVC project to .NET Core and I have the following controller method (.NET 4):

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")] // Never Cache
public virtual ActionResult Extend()
{
     // Re-establish the session timeout
     Session.Timeout = Utility.Constants.sessionTimout;
     return new EmptyResult();
}
```

This is my code in .NET Core

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
//[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")] // Never Cache
public virtual ActionResult Extend()
{
    // Re-establish the session timeout
    // TODO: Need to find out in ASP.NET CORE
    
    //this.HttpContext.SessionSession.Timeout = Utility.Constants.sessionTimout;
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

I have been trying to find out how to do `Session.Timeout` in .NET Core but haven't been lucky.

** UPDATE **
This method restarts timeout from an external application that is loaded into an IFrame. So when user is in the iFrame app, the main ASP.NET application is not getting any interaction at all. So that's why I require to extend the session timeout manually from the iFrame app.

Any clue?

Comment: Whats the error / behavior?

Comment: The above code is the .NET Framework

Comment: i don't get it... session timeout obviously is reset on any communication with the session owner, as the name implies... so any empty endpoint should do

Comment: and you'd initially configure the session timeout with [`builder.Services.AddSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-session-state)

Comment: and sorry it's not any empty endpoint, since it actually needs to be called each time, it should have deactivated caching like in you sample or simply be a `POST` endpoint since they're not cached by default.

Comment: Let me update the post to explain a little bit better because this method what it does is to manually extend the session from an external iFrame application

Comment: ** UPDATE **
This method restarts timeout from an external application that is loaded into an IFrame. So when user is in the iFrame app, the main ASP.NET application is not getting any interaction at all. So that's why I require to extend the session timeout manually from the iFrame app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `TimeOut` property being available in .net core.

But, it is possible to use `Session` state as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#session-state)

You can set the timeout during setup:

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

A call to your `Extend` action should be sufficient to reset the idle timers.

Keep in mind, accessing the `Session` state is different in .net core, e.g.:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("foo", "bar");
string foo = HttpContext.Session.GetString("foo");
```

---

Typically, even within the `IFrame`, the using interacting with the page should be sufficient to reset the `IdleTimeout`.

As @Aria you can even detect the upcoming timeout and act accordingly.

Comment: I just updated the post on why I need to restart session manually. Here is the explanation:

** UPDATE **
This method restarts timeout from an external application that is loaded into an IFrame. So when user is in the iFrame app, the main ASP.NET application is not getting any interaction at all. So that's why I require to extend the session timeout manually from the iFrame app.

Comment: @VAAA: but if the user is interacting with the IFrame, and the IFrame is calling `Extend`, the session idle timeout would be reset, right?

Comment: Mmm good question... I dont really know

Comment: Can you test it? Might be worth it :-)

Comment: Do you know how to get the reamining session time programatically so I can test that

Comment: Hmm... don't know... but, I believe there is a relation with the cookie. The cookie should have a expire time. Not sure if its representative but worth a try I guess

Comment: @VAAA ASP.Net is a request-response technology, why you want extend timeout programmatically, instead you can detect in `IFrame` if session getting timeout and redirect user to another page or something else, if you need more time just set Timeout in App config or App-Start as you need.

Comment: @Aria: I reasoned something similar. I'll process your comment in the answer.